# How to populate a HTML div from array object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I was YouTube video on ReactJS where it populate a div container from a array object using .map() . Is there any way to do it using vanilla js or jquery in simple **HTML** ?
ReactJS code is provided below -

**ProductCategories.JSX**

```
import { categories } from "../dataList";
import CategoryItem from "./CategoryItem";

<div className="* * *">
  {categories.map((item) => (
  <CategoryItem item={item} key={item.id} />
  ))}
</div>
```

**CategoryItem.JSX**

```
import styled from "styled-components";

<Container>
  <Image src={item.Image} />
  <Info>
    <Title>{item.Title}</Title>
    <Button>SHOP NOW</Button>
  </Info>
</Container>
```

**dataList.js**

```
export const categories = [
  {
    id: 1,
    Image: "https://i.ibb.co/CnkbTqm/download-ixid-Mnwx.jpg",
    Title: "Lorem",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    Image: "https://i.ibb.co/CnkbTqm/download-ixid.jpg",
    Title: "Ipsum",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    Image: "https://i.ibb.co/CnkbTqm/download.png",
    Title: "lorem",
  },
];
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please [edit] your question to add your own attempt, and were you got stuck. Consider reading [ask].

Comment: you have to make a giant string with those element them inject it into DOM

Comment: Are you just asking how to write to the page with jQuery?  How exactly is React code relevant here?  It's not really clear what specifically you're asking or in what way your code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @David Yes in jQuery. So there is no relevance directly but i want to do the same thing in HTML so that i don't need to  Hard code the image links in the source code .

Comment: @AmitDeka: Well, you’d start by making an attempt.  If the underlying problem you’re trying to solve is that you don’t know jQuery then you can start with some introductory tutorials and examples.  When you try, what doesn’t work as expected?

Comment: @AmitDeka You can, doesn't mean you should. Libraries like react are there to help you. It's gonna help you a lot in the future if you learn a JS framework

Answer (score 2):

One way, using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

1. Loop through the categories using `reduce()`, for each object return a string (concatenating the previous value) that contains:

   1. A `<h1>` created with `cat.Title`
   2. A `<img>` created with `cat.Image`
2. Set the string as `innerHTML` of your element
   <sup>Using `<body>` as demo</sup>

```js
const categories = [{id: 1, Image: "https://i.ibb.co/CnkbTqm/download-ixid-Mnwx.jpg", Title: "Lorem", }, {id: 2, Image: "https://i.ibb.co/CnkbTqm/download-ixid.jpg", Title: "Ipsum", }, {id: 3, Image: "https://i.ibb.co/CnkbTqm/download.png", Title: "lorem", }, ];

document.body.innerHTML = categories.reduce((prev, cat) => prev + `<h2>${cat.Title}</h2> <img src='${cat.Image}' />`, '');
```

---

We can get the same idea/behaviour/output using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) instead off `reduce()` like so:

```js
const categories = [{id: 1, Image: "https://i.ibb.co/CnkbTqm/download-ixid-Mnwx.jpg", Title: "Lorem", }, {id: 2, Image: "https://i.ibb.co/CnkbTqm/download-ixid.jpg", Title: "Ipsum", }, {id: 3, Image: "https://i.ibb.co/CnkbTqm/download.png", Title: "lorem", }, ];

document.body.innerHTML = categories.map(cat => `<h2>${cat.Title}</h2> <img src='${cat.Image}' />`).join('');
```

Comment: i tried to doing it using your .map() answer but its not giving me the desired design instead it create a new h2 and img element in the my card.

Comment: Could you share that in your question using the edit button? Not sure what you're trying to say. Maybe you'll need an `<div>` around those elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can use createElement() api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

here are some ideas in vanilla

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
var link = document.createElement('a');
var article = document.createElement('article');
```

and here in Jquery

```
var elem = $('<div></div>')
```

you can create element and append to the them container.